# Previous Rows/Markers disappear once new rows/markers are created in Google Scatter Chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am creating a google scatter chart. I want to dynamically update markers/rows. The problem is that while they are being updated dynamically, each time a new row is created the previous one disappears. I want to see the new rows as well as the old ones. The rows are being dynamically updated from combobox item selection. However, the previous row disappears when the new combobox item is selected. I want to see all the row on my chart. My code is::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=0;
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);          
    function drawChart() 
       {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var strUser=[0];
        var strUser2=[0];
        if(i==0)
        {
         var strUser=[0];
         var strUser2=[0];         
        }
        else
        {            
         var a= document.getElementById("combo1");
        strUser[i] = parseInt(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);                   
        var b= document.getElementById("combo2");
        strUser2[i] = parseInt(b.options[b.selectedIndex].value);
         }
        var options = 
        {
          title: 'x vs. y ',
          legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 150 },
          hAxis: {title: 'x', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'y', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
        };
         data.addColumn('number', 'x');
         data.addColumn('number', 'y');
         var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));;

        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
        data.addRows(i+1);
        data.addRows([[strUser[j],strUser2[j]]]);   
        }
        i=i+1;
        chart.draw(data, options);                     
      }
for html:
<body>
<select name="combo1" id="combo1" onchange="drawChart()">
  <option value="0">X</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>  
</select>
<select name="combo2" id="combo2" onchange="drawChart()">
  <option value="0">Y</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>  
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you always create a new datatable, to keep the previous values you must store the datatable somewhere when you call  `drawChart` the first time and use the stored datatable in subsequent calls.

Example(stores the datatable as property of the node where you draw the chart)

```js
    var i=0;
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);          
    function drawChart() 
       {
        var container=document.getElementById('chart_div');
        if(!container.datatable){
          container.datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          container.datatable.addColumn('number', 'x');
          container.datatable.addColumn('number', 'y');
        }
        data=container.datatable
        
        var strUser=[0];
        var strUser2=[0];
        if(i==0)
        {
         var strUser=[0];
         var strUser2=[0];         
        }
        else
        {            
         var a= document.getElementById("combo1");
        strUser[i] = parseInt(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);                   
        var b= document.getElementById("combo2");
        strUser2[i] = parseInt(b.options[b.selectedIndex].value);
         }
        var options = 
        {
          title: 'x vs. y ',
          legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 150 },
          hAxis: {title: 'x', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'y', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
        };
         
         var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
        data.addRows([[strUser[j],strUser2[j]]]);   
        }
        i=i+1;
        chart.draw(data, options);                     
      }
```

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<select name="combo1" id="combo1" onchange="drawChart()">
  <option value="0">X</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>  
</select>
<select name="combo2" id="combo2" onchange="drawChart()">
  <option value="0">Y</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>  
</select>
<div id="chart_div" ></div>
```

Comment: Hi Dr. Molle. Thanks!! This helped. However, there is one more way of doing the same. This is by declaring strUser outside and not re-initializing it again in the function. This was happening because it was being  re-initialized everytime function drawChart() was called  as a result it tended to overwrite strUser[0] value and array later values were erased. So once I declared strUser outside drawchart it startted working fine. So both the solns work well. Thanks Cheers!!